# Class methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to learn how to apply basic object oriented concepts to Javascript.  Here, I just want to be able to create a class method, and then call the method externally when I click on an `<input>` element:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Foo = function()
{

}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() { alert("blah"); }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="submit" onclick = "Foo.bar()">
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work.  Firefox gives the error Error: `Foo.bar is not a function`

However, if I call `Foo()` directly, and then from within `Foo` I call `this.bar()`, it works fine.  Why am I unable to invoke `Foo.bar()` externally?

Comment: Have you been though the W3C schools tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/ ?  I've been programming Javascript since it was called LiveScript and I still reference this site.

Comment: Careful with w3schools—see http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're confusing so-called **instance methods** and **class methods**.

`prototype` is used to create **instance methods**, which belong to objects created from the `prototype` when used with the `new` keyword:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.bar(); // Will work
```

I'm not sure this is what you want. More likely you just want to add a **static class method** to `Foo`:

```
var Foo = {};
Foo.bar = function () { alert('blah'); };
Foo.bar(); // Will work
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Foo.prototype.bar...` just use `Foo.bar = function() {...}`, which will just add a `bar` member on the `Foo` function object.

To access any `prototype` or `this.*` members, you need an instance first: `new Foo().bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a few years back explains; it explains the ins-and-outs of JavaScript class structure:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3600451/Javascript-Basics-Part-8.htm